# Is there a way to import Facebook messages into Gmail?

Tags: gmail, facebook

Is it possible to import my Facebook messages into Gmail?

Answer (score 2):

[Not possible](http://dataportability.org/2011/01/12/true-data-portability/). Once [IMAP for facebook](http://www.emailserviceguide.com/2010/01/making-facebooks-messaging-system-imap-compatible/) gets out of the paper, it [will be](http://www.dataliberation.org/google/gmail).

Unless, [of course](http://downloadsquad.switched.com/2008/01/03/scobleized-why-facebook-will-never-give-your-data-back/), you want to do some "[data mining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_extraction)" using some resource and go against [the law](http://www.facebook.com/terms.php). Sorry I still couldn't find any!